# Unable to run wow64 on server 2008R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I can verify that the SYSWOW64 folder is present. Attempts to run the command line /enable-feature nets: error 0x800f080c feature name servercore-wow64 is unknown.

Now I can see the folder, I can verify it's there, but I can't seem to kick it off. I try the /get-features command, but it doesn't list wow64, or any wow for that matter anywhere in the features. Is there a different command?

I found KB article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977787 where it mentions a manifest issue, but the hotfix is not listed for download. I don't know if that's my issue as well, but perhaps?

Just to cover the basics, this is for a fax server. I have attempted the 32 bit install from the MFG disk(failed), and I have downloaded drivers from their website. When I go to the fax that's installed as 64bit, there's the normal button for "install additional drivers". When I hit it, it asks for the location of the x86 drivers. I point it to the mfg 32 bit drivers, and get a "invalid for processor architecture" error. From there I tried to run WOW64, but as you can read above, it's not listed as a feature, and errors when I try and install it.

The machines that I'm working with are XP pro, and this server 2008r2 Standard. Some suggestions have been to have a 32 bit Vista machine on the domain, install the drivers on it and point the "additional driver" request to it, but I don't have one on the domain. I could most likely scrounge up a 32 bit Win 7 to install the drivers on and point it to that machine, but it can't stay on the domain, as it would be my personal computer. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

OCLIST will show you a list of components supported; OCSETUP should help install those components based on their names.

But bottom line, use the GUI version, you'll be happier.

Edit from comments:

You seem to be describing a problem with Server Core, which is the cut-down version of Windows Server 2008 R2, and boots to the command line.

If you're not using that you're using the GUI version already, and WOW64 is always enabled; you can run 32-bit and 64-bit apps, but not 16-bit. (run IE; in Task Manager if one says *32, you're on a 64-bit copy of Windows with Wow64 working)

If the driver says "invalid processor architecture", check it's 32 or 64 bit and for the right processor type.

Or rather, look for other possible causes that don't include WOW64.

Comment: Sorry for the daft question, still getting used to server 2008: when you say use the gui version, what is it and where might it be located?

Comment: You seem to be describing a problem with Server Core, which is the cut-down version of Windows Server 2008 R2, and boots to the command line. If you're not using that you're using the GUI version already, and WOW64 is always enabled; you can run 32-bit and 64-bit apps, but not 16-bit. (run IE; in Task Manager if one says *32, you're on a 64-bit copy of Windows with Wow64 working) If the driver says "invalid processor architecture", check it's 32 or 64 bit and for the right processor type. Or rather, look for other possible causes that don't include WOW64.